std::bad_alloc when loading PyTorch model in C++ using LibTorch

I'm trying to load a traced PyTorch model in C++ using LibTorch but encountering a std::bad_alloc error. I've set up a minimal example to demonstrate the issue.
The Problem:
When running my C++ application that loads a PyTorch model, it crashes with:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)

cpp code :
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <torch/script.h>

int main()
{
    // Load the traced model
    torch::jit::script::Module module;

    // Load the saved model - update path to your .pt file
    module = torch::jit::load("net.pt");


    return 0;
}

CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18)
project(torch_example)

include(FetchContent)

set(LIBTORCH_CPU_URL "https://download.pytorch.org/libtorch/cpu/libtorch-shared-with-deps-2.5.1%2Bcpu.zip")

FetchContent_Declare(
    Torch
    URL ${LIBTORCH_CPU_URL }
    DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP TRUE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Torch)

add_executable(torch_example main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(torch_example PRIVATE "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
target_include_directories(torch_example PRIVATE "${torch_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set_target_properties(torch_example PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 23)


That means that you do not have enough free memory available for the model.

that doesnt make any sense i have 13gb ram left

that doesnt make any sense i have 13gb ram left -- 1) It makes a lot of sense if the application is 32-bit.  You can have 100gb or ram, a 32-bit application can only access 4Gb or less.  2) A std::bad_alloc can be thrown if the argument being given to new[] is negative.  See this.

Can you load your traced your serialized net in a python code and run a random input through it to check that it was properly serialized and is not broken or corrupted in any way  ? Also, please link when you crosspost : https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/getting-std-bad-alloc-when-loading-the-python-tradined-model-in-c/212797

@trialNerror so i made a seperate c++ project and it works. but not on the my other big project i checked compiler configuration it all looks good

Okay then, can you elaborate on that separate C++ project ? How does it differ from the code that fail ? Can you confirm that your code and setup above does reproduce your error ? If not, you will need to work backward from your big project, iteratively removing files and lines until you get a minimal code that reproduces the problem

i found out that when linking a pch (precompiled header) it happens, if not it works
